# Generate bean definition of multiple classes automatically

Tags: eclipse, spring, code-generation, spring-bean

How can I create bean definition of multiple classes in spring? I know the spring TS helps to create bean definition but can it used to create for multiple classes at one time?

```
<bean id="class1" class="com.test.Class1">
</bean>

<bean id="class2" class="com.test.Class2">
</bean>

<bean id="class3" class="com.test.Class3">
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, following bean configuration file is perfectly valid:

```
<bean id="class1a" class="com.test.Class1">
</bean>

<bean id="class1b" class="com.test.Class1">
</bean>
```

You will get 2 instances of Class1 with different bean name. You just need to be careful when autowiring (esp. by type)